# Is it acceptable to use the onclick event handler in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a simple nav menu with submenus. When the links in the submenu are clicked while on the same page, the window scrolls using jQuery to the respective anchor.

Here is an example of a submenu list item:

```
<li><a href="page.html#some-anchor" onclick="clickScroll('#some-anchor');"><span>foo</span></a></li>
```

The corresponding anchor looks like this:

```
<a class="hidden-anchor" id="some-anchor" name="some-anchor"></a>
```

The JavaScript function:

```
function clickScroll(dest) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(dest).offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

It all works perfectly fine, but like many before me I have been reading that inline event handlers are bad practice these days.

How can I modify the function to eliminate the need for any `onclick` calls? Keep in mind that each submenu link corresponds to a different anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want all anchors with a hash `#` to scroll to a corresponding anchor with the same ID, you can loop through all anchors, parse out the hash and scroll to the same ID:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if ( this.hash ) {
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 1000);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
     }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nGfW5/

If you want to limit this functionality to certain anchors, add a class and insert it in the selector, f.ex `$('a.hashlink').each(`

Comment: I tried this method, as well as Mythril's, but it seems as though the href is being parsed before the click function can be called, since the page just goes to the anchor like normal instead of scrolling. Is this possible? If so, should I remove the hrefs (or perhaps just change them to '#') and just use corresponding ids (ie. #some-anchor-link)?

Comment: Your example did work (providing you squash the result window) but I cannot get it to work in my code. Like you suggested, I added the class .submenu-link to all anchors in the submenu and changed the selector to $('a.submenu-link').

Comment: I think the issue might be the hrefs of the submenu links are "page.html#some-anchor" and the link is trying to scroll to an anchor with that id. Is that right?

Comment: @Bobe no, the script uses the hash of the href (`this.hash`), which is `#some-anchor`. This is how my fiddle works. You should probably add some logs and see where your code breaks.

Comment: Ah I got it. I neglected to put the script inside the (document).ready() function. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use event handlers: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
<li><a id="some-scroll-source" href="page.html#some-anchor"><span>foo</span></a></li>

<a class="hidden-anchor" id="some-anchor" name="some-anchor"></a>

(function () {
    function clickScroll() {
        var dest = $('#' + ($(this).attr('href').split('#')[1]));
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(dest).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }

    $('#some-scroll-source').on('click', clickScroll);;
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('li a').each (function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
           scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to scroll to the ID of the corresponding anchor, not the anchor that was clicked.